# How to force tap on UIBarButtonItem using RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

This is what I do to setup `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
mainView.userBarButtonItem.rx.tap.bind { _ in
    self.router.presentUserController(from: self)
}.disposed(by: bag)
```

but now I need to do something to call that closure. How?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Will work fine

```
    mainView.userBarButtonItem.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
        self.router.presentUserController(from: self)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, this will work;) I know... but how to FORCE that subscription to call from code?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a click by doing:

```
if let target = mainView.userBarButtonItem.target, let action = mainView.userBarButtonItem.action {
  _ = target.perform(action, with: mainView.userBarButtonItem)
}
```

Will work after having subscribed to the `tap` sequence.

However, I don't really see why you would need to do this. I hope this is not for unit-testing...

Comment: indeed this is for unit testing;) I need to check if router receive a callback when that button is pressed

Comment: You should use `UI Testing` for that, not Unit Testing ... Anyway, the above will trigger the `rx` observable sequence as `rx` sets itself as target and action when you subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(barButtonItem.action!, to: barButtonItem.target, from: self, for: nil)
```